# How to interact with Heroku from a js file

Tags: python, web, heroku

I have a python file named myfile uploaded on github and heroku app linked to that github repo.

Now when I run `heroku run myfile.py` on CLI of heroku it is working fine with the output as a string.

Also ,

- I have a html page (in the same repo) hosted by heroku .

So what I want is when user clicks a button in the page,

- `heroku run myfile.py` command should be run on heroku .
- and my page should fetch the output string from heroku .
- output should be displayed on the page .

Anybody knows how to do this (in the script section of html ) ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to change how `myfile.py` works, and to have it expose an API.

Using a tool such as [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/), you could expose an HTTP endpoint to your app.
Your Javascript would then be able to make a call to that endpoint, and retrieve any response it sends.

See [Getting started with Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python).